# Weird Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, syntax

I'm working with MySQL 5.6 on a Ubuntu 14.04 server.

Checking in this online syntax checker: https://sql.treasuredata.com/

The syntax checker tool throws the exception:  mismatched input 'NOT' expecting ) near 'int' in create table statement.  Why is this syntax incorrect?  If you're specifying NOT NULL on a data type it is placed after the data type and before auto increment without a comma, isn't that correct?

```
CREATE TABLE users (id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, email varchar(60) NOT NULL, ripple varchar(60) NOT NULL, fname varchar(60) NOT NULL, lname varchar(60) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id));
CREATE TABLE public (id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, user_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, key varchar(60) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id));
CREATE TABLE private (id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, key varchar(60) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id));
CREATE TABLE redeem (id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,PRIMARY KEY(id));
```

Update:  changing the key columns does not seem to be causing this syntax error:

```
CREATE TABLE users (id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, email  varchar(60) NOT NULL, ripple varchar(60) NOT NULL, fname varchar(60) NOT NULL, lname varchar(60) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id));
CREATE TABLE public (id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, user_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, pubkey varchar(60) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id));
CREATE TABLE private (id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, privkey varchar(60) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id));
CREATE TABLE redeem (id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,PRIMARY KEY(id));
```

Closing Update:  key is a reserved keyword, fixed this error by changing these fields to pubkey and privkey.  AUTO INCREMENT was specified twice in a table when it was accidentally left in when copying and pasting SQL.

Comment: You had 2 auto-increments in the same table (not allowed) and 2 columns named `key` (not allowed, reserved). Otherwise the statements are valid in MySQL: [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/496d9)

Comment: Reserved words:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/keywords.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using SQL Fiddle, [it's fine](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ff2da/1/0):

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  email varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  ripple varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  fname varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  lname varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Comment: Thanks for this resource, checking the rest of these tables.

Comment: AUTO INCREMENT accidentally was copied into the redeem table SQL.
I was unaware key is a reserved keyword, fixed by changing those values to pubkey and privkey.
Thanks for providing this SQl tool, I was unaware that the one I was using was for unique build of MySQL, not v5.6 which was installed on my server.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error was using two AUTO INCREMENT statements.  The user_id field within public does not need to auto increment, it is imported from the user's table.